# How To Receive Email Using IMAP From Gmail Whilst On Proxy With Firewall?

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, imap, firewall

Ok so I have a working program, it is only a very basic proof of concept type thing - no time poured into it or anything!
It works when I am not on my work connection, i.e. when I am at home or using a dongle. What I want to find out is how I can modify it to work when on the work network?
When I run it on the work network I get this error message:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it :"
However I currently have no idea how to get through either the firewall or the proxy whichever may be disturbing the process!!!

I am using the [AE.Net.Mail](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) library to interact with the IMAP.

Here is the code:

```
using AE.Net.Mail;

//IMAP ATTEMPT
try
{
// Connect to the Google IMAP server.
using (ImapClient Imap = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "Address@googlemail.com", "Password", ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
{
// Select the mailbox you want to read messages from.
Imap.SelectMailbox("INBOX");

//Displays the count of messages in selected mailbox.
label1.Text = Imap.GetMessageCount().ToString();

// Get the first 100 messages from selected mailbox. 0 is the first message
// MailMessage is a message in your mailbox, so this is an array of 100 messages from you selected mailbox.
MailMessage[] mm = Imap.GetMessages(0, 99);

//Loops through selected messages putting the subject in the listbox.
foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(m.Subject);
}
}
}
catch (Exception exn)
{
//Show error message when error occurs.
errorProvider1.SetError(label1, exn.Message);
textBox1.Text = exn.Message;
}
```

I have tried adding the following to App.config (just as a punt really)!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

If anyone could shed some light on what I am missing or something I need to look-up that would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Code of the ImapClient as described in this link: https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/issues/21

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply! I have had a look at the solution you linked but I can't quite seem to implement it :( I don't get how the ImapClient constructor is either overridden, intercepted or even directly modified! A few other things elude me also. I have asked for some clarification on the post however so I hope to get a response! Thank you for the link!